# Eveytime when I try to use require_once("Connectdb.php"), the webpage shows nothing

Tags: php, mysql, require, bluehost

I am useing Bluehost web hosting and the website that I am building is located in the subdomain, every time when I try to use

```
require_once("Connectdb.php") or die ("require fail!");
```

the web page shows nothing, just a blank page.

I tried using

```
require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))."/Connectdb.php");
```

but still, a blank page is returned...

Comment: It's probably a fatal error in Connectdb.php that prevents it from compiling successfully - do a command line php -l on the file

Comment: require_once or die will not work, can you ensure the path to file is correctly set? turn on your display_error, and include what is inside Connectdb.php

Comment: Check your logs and try enabling error reporting on your development environment as suggested by Dunhamzzz.

Comment: But there are just a few define() funtions

Comment: @user1022254 - And you can guarantee that none of those defines functions contains any error? or that include() is actually finding the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is "white screening" because it has an error but your server has errors turned off so there's no output. Put these at the top of the very first file (possibly index?)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

And normal errors should show on the page. A fatal error (like require_once) will still stop the script from executing though.